Split Devise /registrations/edit into separate sections within the same page
Devise's registrations/edit.html.erb allows users to edit their email and password (if any provided). This form also requires current_password to be filled.
I'd like to split this form into separate sections:

one to update the email
a second one to update the password
another one to delete the account
maybe more, like update username or other informations


I've tried several approaches, but generally both forms rely on the same current_user (as resource) and include a password_field(:current_password) as:
# update_email form
<%= form_for(resource, as: :resource_name, url: configurations_update_email_path, html: { method: :put } do |f| %>
  <%= f.email_field :email %>
  <%= f.password_field :current_password %> # <- DUPLICATED
<% end %>

# update_password form
<%= form_for(resource, as: :resource_name, url: configurations_update_password_path, html: { method: :put } do |f| %>
  <%= f.password_field :current_password %> # <- DUPLICATED
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation%>
<% end %>

As those are sensitive forms, both actions use Devise's .update_with_password method to ensure users provided a valid current password. In case they don't, an error is attached to the current_password virtual attribute:
# lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb#L87
def update_with_password
  # ...
  result = if valid_password?(current_password)
    update(params) 
  else
    assign_attributes(params)
    valid?
    errors.add(:current_password, current_password.blank? ? :blank : :invalid)
    false
  end
  # ...
end

Issue is that any error on this field will be displayed on both password_field(:current_password). It can be missleading to users which may think they've to fill both forms.
How can I contain the errors in their respective forms?

The issue here is really that you're binding the same instance of user to both forms when you're rendering. Also why are you doing this? Devise has built in controllers and routes for password updates so the second form should not be submitting to that path.

I'm confused, I thought RegistrationsController#update was meant to update users informations, whereas PasswordsController#update was meant to reset the password while unauthenticated (since it relies on reset_password_token). In my case I wanted to split Devise's views/registrations/edit into autonomous sections

I realize I didn't answered your question. It may be naive, but as it updates current_user, I'm using it to all forms. Maybe I coud do something like form_for((local_assigns[:resource_with_error] || current_user.dup), ...) in all form but it seems akward to me. I've edited my question btw (and tried other approaches without success yet)

I would look at the FormObject pattern and wrap the resource in different form objects. Or look at how the devise views handle it.

can these both be rendered in a turbo stream?  Don't reload both sections on error, just the specific form.

Yes they're, but I want the application to work even without JS. I went for form object pattern and it seems clean (I can share my code if anyone is interested)
